# pugixml for CentOS7 32bit

Tags: centos7, 32-bit, pugixml

sorry in advance if the question is a trivial one.

I have a 32-bit machine running CentOS7, and I would need to install the `pugixml` package (v >= 1.0); so far, I didn't manage to (the standard `sudo yum install pugixml-devel` does not work with this setup).

Could somebody please provide help? Thanks!

Comment: This seems off-topic for SO, and anyway "does not work" is not a problem description. What exact output do you get?

Comment: This is part of the output: `No package pugixml-devel available`.

Comment: Given this, how could I find out if there is a version of `pugixml` that can be installed on this machine (CentOS7, 32-bit)? It doesn't have to be the latest version of `pugixml`, it only needs to be v>=1.0.